# OWIN how to configure /signout-oidc to remove cookies

Tags: c#, .net, owin, openid, openid-connect

I'm creating applications that are authorized by a personal run OIDC server.
The server is using Openiddict library, and the applications are using OWIN for the configuration. this is because the OIDC server is running on .Net core and the applications on .Net framework.

When trying to log out from these applications I redirect to the OIDC server /Account/Logout, this will in turn get all the logged in applications and open an iframe with the front channel logout url (/signout-oidc).

When logging out, it will give a 404 not found, meaning that the url "example.com/signout-oidc" has not been created.

The used libraries for the application are:

- Microsoft.Owin.Security
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect

```cs
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.Use(async (Context, next) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("1 ==>request, before cookie auth");
                await next.Invoke();
                Debug.WriteLine("6 <==response, after cookie auth");
            });

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.Use(async (Context, next) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("2 ==>after cookie, before OIDC");
                await next.Invoke();
                Debug.WriteLine("5 <==after OIDC");
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
                {
                    ClientId = "application-client-id",
                    ClientSecret = "application-client-secret",
                    Scope = "openid profile email",
                    Authority = "personal-oidc-link",
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                    RedirectUri = "https://example.com/signin-oidc",
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier
                    },
                });
            app.Use(async (Context, next) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("3 ==>after OIDC, before leaving the pipeline");
                await next.Invoke();
                Debug.WriteLine("4 <==after entering the pipeline, before OIDC");
            });
```

The server configuration:

```
services.AddOpenIddict()
                .AddCore(options =>
                {
                    // Configure OpenIddict to use the Entity Framework Core stores and entities.
                    options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                        .UseDbContext<DataContext>()
                        .ReplaceDefaultEntities<CompanyApplication, CompanyAuthorization, CompanyScope, CompanyToken, Guid>();
                })
                .AddServer(options =>
                {
                    options.UseMvc();

                    options.UseJsonWebTokens();
                    options.AddEphemeralSigningKey("RS512");
                    // options.AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

                    if (this.environment.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
                    }

                    // Enable the authorization, logout, token and userinfo endpoints.
                    options
                        .EnableAuthorizationEndpoint("/oidc/authorize")
                        .EnableLogoutEndpoint("/Account/Logout")
                        .EnableTokenEndpoint("/oidc/token")
                        .EnableUserinfoEndpoint("/oidc/userinfo");

                    options
                        .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
                        .AllowImplicitFlow()
                        .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

                    options.RegisterClaims(
                        CompanyClaims.FriendlyName,
                        CompanyClaims.Email,
                        CompanyClaims.EmailVerified,
                        CompanyClaims.Sub,
                        CompanyClaims.Group,
                        CompanyClaims.GivenName,
                        CompanyClaims.MiddleName,
                        CompanyClaims.FamilyName);

                    // Mark the "email", "profile" and "roles" scopes as supported scopes.
                    options.RegisterScopes(
                        OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Email,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles);
                });
```

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    o =>
                    {
                        o.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Denied";
                        o.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                        o.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";

                        o.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                        o.Cookie.Name = "session";
                        o.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
                        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
                    });
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseResponseCaching();

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
```

I expect that OWIN generates the /signout-oidc route, and when called it deletes the authentication cookie.

Edit: Added some more configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience with the openiddict library here. But I'm using the IdentityServer library.

I've learned that in the OpenId Connect flow to remove the cookies using the FrontChannel logout you need to:

```
o.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
```

By doing this, the GET request to /signout-oidc, initiated by your OpenId server will contain the authentication cookie of the user currently logging out. So, the middleware handling the /signout-oidc request knows which user is doing the logout and is able to logout that user.

You can use the Developer Tools in your browser (don't forget to enable 'Preserve log' when using Chrome) to find the GET /signout-oidc request and see if it contains the authentication cookie.

A second option is to choose using a backchannel logout flow, don't know if the openiddict supports this.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use

```
PostLogoutRedirectUri = ""
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I've added this option to the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` with an empty value and with "https://example.com/signout-oidc".  Both still resulted in the same 404.

Comment: Can you share your openId configuration as well as your web site configuration, the PostLogoutRedirect to redirect to your website address.

Comment: Added the configuration. I've currently made a work around where i've manually created an endpoint that deletes the cookie and call that from the oidc server.